# What is the best way to determine when a campaign has had a new contact added to it?

Tags: rest-api, rest, campaign

If I want to use Salesforce's REST API to return campaigns who have recently had members added to them, what is the easiest way to do so? I am trying to do this externally, using authentication information to pull data from Salesforce in a different application. Is using `Campaign.SystemModstamp` the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. This flag can be updated for any of a number of reasons (e.g. a user edited a field). Instead, a query might help:

```
SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Id IN 
  (SELECT CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY)
```

(Replace TODAY with any other date literal or a specific date range).

Comment: This accomplishes what I'm looking for with a well-designed query. It wasn't immediately obvious to me how to access this data using the correct filter. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No code needed for this.  **Go to Workflow Rules** -> add a new Worklflow rule when a member is added to a campaign.
In the rule criteria put `NOT(ISBLANK( ContactId ))​`
Send email Alert that includes the member name
see screen snap
[image]