# How to determine when someone has been removed from a campaign (REST API)

Tags: rest-api, rest, sql, campaign, campaign-member

Similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307085/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-when-a-campaign-has-had-a-new-contact-added-to/307090#307090) question, I'd like to be able to fire off a query (from an external application) to determine when someone is **removed** from a Salesforce Campaign. The question I linked has a good solution for determining when a campaign is modified [(provided by a user)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/307088/83587) like so:

```
SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Id IN 
  (SELECT CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY)
```

Using similar logic (and assuming I can't just view these things in Salesforce itself), how can I determine if someone is removed from a campaign? There doesn't seem to be a `CampaignMember` field available for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a textbook use case for [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/), which [supports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_object_support.htm) `CampaignMember`.

Your remote application would subscribe to Change Data Capture events for the `CampaignMember` object and could then consume events where those records are deleted. You wouldn't need to run any queries, which would be a dicey approach anyway since anything that was hard deleted wouldn't be available under any circumstances.

An alternate approach would be to use the [Sobject Get Deleted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getdeleted.htm) API endpoint, which will allow you to poll for information about deleted records in any sObject.

Comment: This all seems very useful. However, I'm curious- is there no field that will return to me when/if a Campaign has someone removed from it? Like a `ModifiedDate` that changes when a `CampaignMember` is removed? I have very limited access to this client's Salesforce instance, so I'm trying to figure out how to do as much of this work externally as I can.

Comment: You may be able to scrape information from the roll-up fields and LastModifiedDate on the parent Campaign, but it's not going to provide you with the granularity that it sounds like you need.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a good place to look. The specific project I'm working on is a two-way integration between our application and a customer's Salesforce instance, where I'm trying to detect when people are added/removed from a Salesforce Campaign in order to be able to determine when to add/remove those Contacts from our distribution lists. I was thinking it would be a little easier to determine when those movements happened, but it seems like it might take a little more doing from the Salesforce side.

Comment: I really think you need to poll the SObject Get Deleted endpoint if you don't want to use Change Data Capture. If a Campaign is large, resyncing the whole Campaign every time it changes is going to be very inefficient.